# git hooks- fetch git commit id

Tags: git, githooks

I want to fetch the current git commit id of the repository either before user pushes to GitHub of after user clones from GitHub. This commit id should then be written onto a file, which is also in the repository. Is it possible to do this using any Git hook?

I have a c++ function that displays the current git id. If a user downloads (.zip) of my repository it should display the commit id that was present GitHub when they downloaded it. If they clone the repo, later commit to it, git id should get updated. Any way to do this?

Comment: I'm not clear on why you're asking for this. It sounds like you're asking for a git hook to write a file in the git repo that records the git commit hashes of that repository. Have you tried `git log`?

Comment: BTW, why are you trying to do this? Since git is a branching based approach, this could have some side effects that you are not anticipating. For instance, will this file containing the commit id be named the same for all users? Do you realize that if you capture the current commit and push to remote that that will not be the commit id of HEAD after your merge to your main branch?

Comment: `Do you realize that if you capture the current commit and push to remote that that will not be the commit id of HEAD after your merge to your main branch?` Yes, it needs to be same. Id should be updated. So is there any way to achieve this? Have a file that always stores the current git  commit id?

Comment: Might as well ask how to dribble a baseball.  What's the point, here? What's this in aid of?

Comment: I'm not able to figure out what more I should add to the question. What exactly is missing? What is the additional info required?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this, not sure why, but it is possible.

Note, git uses branches, so you have to know what branch is your main branch, let's assume `master`.

1. Use the [`git log` command](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History) with some options to get the commit id from the remote HEAD on your main branch.

   `$ git log origin/master -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H"`
2. Output this to a file.

   `$ git log origin/master -n 1 --pretty=format:"%H" > top_commit.txt`
3. Put this in a shell script so you can reuse.
4. Add a githook to the desired event, which I assume will be `pre-commit`. For more on that, see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks.

There are some limits to what you can do. For instance, I know you can do this for pre-commit, but not sure about the need to do so when cloning. Also, client side githooks will have to be installed. You'll need to write a script to install those for your users.

**UPDATE**

Something akin to what you are asking is possible, but not exactly; I do not think it possible to grab the commit *being made* and shove it in a file, then include that file in the same commit.

Furthermore, I'm not sure why you want to do this as `git log` has a full history of what occurred.

There are valid reasons to want to know and use the commit id at HEAD, but we'd need to know why, when, where, how, etc., to help you further.

Comment: You'll still want to use the `git log` command with options above, when you do it is up to you based on what you're wanting to do. I'll update based on what I thinking you're trying to do now.

Comment: commit id is not generated pre-commit. If i use post-commit, change made to the file is not committed, so it is not pushed to GitHub. Is there any other way?

Comment: No. I misunderstood what you were trying to do. I thought you were attempting to get the commit id of HEAD from your origin repository rather than capture the commit id of your current commit. Please address the purpose, or why, behind this request in your question above it will help tremendously to answer this. There may be another way to achieve your purpose, because currently I can't understand why you want to do this.

Comment: I came across this, I have already a pre-commit script which writes date, LoC, version to a file.  This file is useful when making a non-git archive for distribution, allows one to identify where the code in git is from that archive (version in file -> git tag), would be even better to have the last commit id in that file, but as you say, does not seem possible.